# Routing some hosts though specific interface

Tags: networking, routing

On my mac book i have two interface connections. One is WIFI `en0` and other is LAN `en5`. Both are connecting via DHCP

What I'm trying to do is to route all the host names that resolves to ips 140.x.x.x is to route them though the LAN interface and all the rest should go though WIFI.

I've tried to add a specific route, for example: 
`sudo route add -host 140.177.141.230 -interface en5` but it didn't help.

Anyone have any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: You want to route through the LAN interface and for that you issue `route delete` command?

Comment: @techraf clearly its a copy-paste mistake from my numerous tries and retries and it should of been add...